# Extracting word in with regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to replace `$word` with another word in the following string:

```
"Hello $word How are you"
```

I used `/\$(.*)/`, `/\$(.*)(\s)/` , `/\$(.* \s)/`. Due to `*`, I get the whole string after `$`, but I only need that word; I need to escape the space. I tried `/s,\b`, and few other options, but I cannot figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

`*` is a [**greedy**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap) operator meaning it will match as much as it can and still allow the remainder of the regular expression to match. The token `.*` will greedily match every single character in the string. The regex engine will then advance to the next token `\s` which matches the last whitespace before the word "you" in the string given you a result of `word How are`.

You can use `\S` in place of `.*` which matches any non-whitespace characters.

```
\$\S+
```

Or to simply match only word characters, you can use the following:

```
\$\w+
```

Comment: `"Very $good explanation".sub(/\$\w+/, "nice")`, but I'm not sure the OP needs a capture group.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to replace "$world" using a regex, try this:

```
"Hello $word How are you".gsub(/\$word/, 'other_word')
```

Or:

```
"Hello $word How are you".sub('$word',"*")
```

You can read more for gsub here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub

Answer (score 0):

Substituting placeholder words for other words is usually not done with a regex but with the `%` method and a hash:

```
h = {word: "aaa", other_word: "bbb"} 
p "Hello %{word} How are you. %{other_word}. Bye %{word}" % h
# => "Hello aaa How are you. bbb. Bye aaa"
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
>> string = "Hello $word How are you"
=> "Hello $word How are you"
>> replace_regex = /(?<replace_word>\$\w+)/
=> /(?<replace_word>\$\w+)/
>> string.gsub(replace_regex, "Bob")
=> "Hello Bob How are you"
>> string.match(replace_regex)[:replace_word]
=> "$word"
```

Note:

- `replace_word` is the regex with a *named capture group*.